# How to initialize a class member data with other member data of this class ?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I have class A and B.
B is a member of A. 
I need to initialize B with other data members of A.

```
class A;
class B
{
 public:
    B(A& a){cout << "B constr is run \n";}
};

class A
{
 public:
    A(){}

    void initB(A& a){b(a); cout << "A call init B \n"; }
 private:
    // other members ...

    B b;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.initB(a);

}
```

I got compile error:

```
classIns.cpp: In constructor âA::A()â:
classIns.cpp:14: error: no matching function for call to âB::B()â
classIns.cpp:8: note: candidates are: B::B(A&)
classIns.cpp:6: note:                 B::B(const B&)
classIns.cpp: In member function âvoid A::initB(A&)â:
classIns.cpp:16: error: no match for call to â(B) (A&)â
```

Why A(){} needs to call B::B()  ?

How to initialize B with other data members of A ?

thanks

Comment: Why are there five answers and no instances of "initializer list" <--except that one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B` has no default constructor, which means you *have* to initialise it in `A`'s ctor.

```
struct A {
    A() : b(*this) {}
private:
    B b;
};
```

Any time you think of using `init`-like members, you're probably doing it wrong. Object should always be valid after the constructor is done.

Comment: @user1000107: This is called an initializer list, and is the recommended way to initialize all members.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
void initB(A& a){
  b = B(a); 
  cout << "A call init B \n"; 
}
```

Off course, the class B needs a default constructor, and a copy constructor that takes reference to the object of type A.

Comment: Constructor returns **nothing** so as to assign to something else.

Comment: @Mahesh No, it doesn't. However, the class B should have the assign operator declared as `B& operator=( const A& )`

Comment: In that case, just `b = a;` suffice. The temporary being created is of type `B` and is not compatible with the assignment operator argument you currently have( i.e., const A& ). So, I believe even the `=` operator provided, the snippet won't compile unless you do `b=a;`

Comment: @Mahesh Ok right. Fixed small mistake in my answer (it should be the copy constructor, not constructor, that takes a reference to the object of type A). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use initialization chain in A constructor:

```
class B
{
    public:
        B(Type1 x, Type2 y)
        {

        }
        void init(Type1 x, Type2 y) { ........} 
};
class A
{
    public:
        A() : Amember1(), Amember2(), b(Amember1, Amember2) {}
    private:
        Type1 Amember1;
        .....
        B b;
};
```

But you can't invoke B constructor inside `initB` method because b is already constructed.
You can use a `B::init()` method with A data, like:

```
void A::initB(A& a){ b.init(a.Amember1, a.Amember2); cout << "A call init B \n"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why A(){} needs to call B::B() ?

Because A has a data member B which needs to be initialized when you create an instance of the A class. In your case b is initialized with the default B c'tor.

Since you are specifying a constructor for B

```
public:
    B(A& a){cout << "B constr is run \n";}
```

The default constructor :

```
    B(){}
```

is not automatically generated by the compiler. So it complains.